# Pooled object created by the following code has not been returned to the pool in tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat9

-2

I am facing below error with jdk1.8, tomcat9, Oracle 10g. Could someone help for compatible ojdbc library and any suggestion for below connection pooling error.

- context.xml

in /tomcat9/conf/ is given below configuration
*Resource name="jdbc/AppConnectionDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" logAbandoned="true" maxTotal="25" maxIdle="10" maxWaitMillis="-1" username="XXX" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" password="*****" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx" validationQuery="select 1 from dual"*

**Pooled object created 2024-01-16 21:50:41 +0400 by the following code has not been returned to the pool: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.ThrowableCallStack$Snapshot a**t org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.ThrowableCallStack.fillInStackTrace(ThrowableCallStack.java:66) at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.DefaultPooledObject.allocate(DefaultPooledObject.java:78) at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:318) at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:223) at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:141) at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:731)